# Joining Four SQL Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have four tables as shown below in oracle DB, Employee list is mapped with office Ids (m_office contains office Ids and Office names). All the Offices are either Division or Subdivision. Again All the Subdivisions belong to Divisions. I need to find out division wise employee count (the division count should include employees belong to subdivision as well) as shown in the last table.

(As its a working database so cant change the structure). Not able to find the solution. Any help is highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

**TEST_EMPLOYEELIST**

```
 EmpId  EmpName  Office_id
--------------------------------
1      Alex      O1
2      John      O1
3      Bob       O3
4      Max       O5
5      Nick      O5
6      Jack      O1
7      Paul      O2
```

**TEST_M_OFFICE**

```
  office_id   office_name
------------------------------
O1           Kamrup Division
O2           Nalbari Division
O3           Barpeta Division
O4           Nalbari RR Subdivision
O5           Barpeta SR Subdivision
O6           Barpeta RR Subdivision
```

**TEST_DIVISION**

```
division_id    division_name
-----------------------------------
D1             Kamrup Division
D2             Nalbari Division
D3             Barpeta Division
D4             Bongaigon Division
D5             Rangia Division
```

**TEST_DIV_SUBDIV_MAPPING**

```
subdivision_id    subdivision_name         division_id
------------------------------------------------------
S1                Nalbari RR Subdivision    D2
S2                Barpeta SR Subdivision    D3
S3                Barpeta RR Subdivision    D3
S4                Rangia RR Subdivision     D5
S5                Kamrup RR Subdivision     D1
```

**Required: Division_wise records(Including subdivision count)**

```
division_name         count
----------------------------
Kamrup Division         3
Nalbari Division        1
Barpeta Division        3
Bongaigon Division      0
Rangia Division         0
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
select b.office_name,
       count(*) 
  from test_employeelist a,
       test_m_office b 
 where a.officeid = b.office_id 
 group by b.office_name;
```

Comment: `select b.office_name,count(*) from test_employeelist a,test_m_office b where a.officeid=b.office_id
group by b.office_name;`

But its giving only office-wise count details. I am not able to find a solution for how to map sub-division count in the division from TEST_DIV_SUBDIV_MAPPING table.

Comment: Add the above comment to your question.

Comment: Clarification needed for the Mapping between Division and Offices tables.

Comment: @ Shyam Vemula: office names in TEST_M_OFFICE table are smilar to either division_name in TEST_DIVISION table or subdivision_name in TEST_DIV_SUBDIV_MAPPING table. There is no other direct mapping belween between Division and Offices tables.

Comment: seems you have not relation between office and division ... if you have this relation please tell us

Comment: how did you get the count 3,1,3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT division_name,
       count(*)
FROM
  (SELECT b.office_name division_name
   FROM test_employeelist a,
        test_m_office b,
        TEST_DIVISION c
   WHERE a.office_id=b.office_id
    AND  b.office_name=c.division_name
   UNION ALL 
  SELECT c.division_name division_name
   FROM test_employeelist a,
        test_m_office b,
        TEST_DIVISION c,
        TEST_DIV_SUBDIV_MAPPING d
   WHERE a.office_id=b.office_id
     AND b.office_name = d.subdivision_name
     AND c.division_id = d.division_id )
GROUP BY division_name;
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` is a good answer. But a join syntax that was made redundant in 1992? Really? And alias names a, b, c, d? This is very bad style. Alias names are meant to *help* readability not to hinder it, so use mnemonic names.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad data model. As one cannot create foreign keys on the names, a simple typo gets records unrelated.

However, so you have offices that are divisions and offices that are subdivisions of divisions. Use UNION ALL to combine the two to get an intermediate table relating office and division.

```
select
  dv.division_name,
  count(e.empid) as employee_count
from
(
  select d.division_id, d.division_name, d.division_name as office_name
  from test_division d
  union all
  select d.division_id, d.division_name, sd.subdivision_name as office_name
  from test_div_subdiv_mapping sd
  join test_division d on d.division_name = sd.division_id
) dv
join test_m_office o on o.office_name = dv.office_name
left join test_employeelist e on e.office_id = o.office_id
group by dv.division_id, dv.division_name;
```